# Javascript object variable name as number

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below, i shows up as "i", not the number I am iterating through.  How do I correct this?  Thanks!

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
     var postParams = {
        i : 'avalueofsorts'
     };
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want to create a new object every iteration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0, l = 10000; i < l; ++i) {
     var postParams = {};
     postParams[i] = 'avalueofsorts'
}
```

Per Cybernate's comment, you can create the object beforehand and just populate it otherwise you create it each time. You probably want this:

```
for (var i = 0, l = 10000, postParams = {}; i < l; ++i) {
     postParams[i] = 'avalueofsorts'
}
```

Comment: @Meder: I guess the postParams should be declared outside the for loop other wise it gets defined for every iteration.

Comment: @Frank ~ Note that you're not using an object here, but an array, really. Just a comment.

Comment: Yea, going from Ruby Hashes to Java structs to this I'm trying to figure out semantics still .  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the 'you want an array comment':

```
for (var i = 0, postParams = []; i < 10000; i++) {
     postParams.push('avalueofsorts');
}
```

In javascript arrays are just objects with a few extra methods (push, pop etc...) and a length property.